# How to prove ${\rm Hom}_G(V,V)$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

In representation theory, sometimes they use such property: if V is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and is a simple $G$-module, then ${\rm Hom}_G(V,V) \cong \mathbb{C}$.

I do not know whether my proof is correct. Here is my thought: It may be similar to the proof that  the linear operators which are commute with all the linear operators can only be identity or a constant times the identity.

I think this may be wrong but I do not know how to prove it.

Could you please offer me any help? Any comments with be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about the representation theory, then I assume that $G$ is a group and $V$ is a $G$-module. In this case what you've written is only true if $V$ is simple $G$-module (i.e. the corresponding representation is irreudcible). This follows from Schur's lemma.

Comment: I have seen other ways to approach the Schur's lemma, but in that class the professor first gave this claim(without proof) then used this property to prove the Schur's lemma which makes me confused. But your comment does help, thank you!

Comment: Ah I think I have some idea, this homomorphism is true if V/ $\mathbb{C}$ is an irreducible representation of G, this should be an important property to use in the proof. I will try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the user "richrow". I did not notice that this homomorphism holds only for irreducible representation of $G$; using this, the proof is quite easy.

And here is the proof.

First, I introduce a lemma, for linear operators $A$ and $B$, if $A$ commutes with $B$, i.e. $AB=BA$, then if $V_\lambda$ denotes the eigenspace of $A$, then $V_\lambda$ is invariant under $B$. This lemma should be familiar to people majored in physics(lol), so I omit the proof.

Since $\text{Hom}_G(V,V)$ represents the linear maps which commute with the group element, then for any $T \in \text{Hom}_G(V,V)$, the eigenspace of $T$ should be invariant under $G$.

Recall that $(\rho, V)$ is an irreducible representation, there should have no non-trivial subspace of $V$ which is invariant under $G$. Note that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, there are always the eigenspace of $T$. So this eigenspace should be either $\{0\}$ or $V$. The $\{0\}$ case is dump while the case of $V$ indicates that $T=\lambda I_n.$

Comment: Note that this proof relies on existence of eingenvalues/eingenvectors, so problably you should suppose $V$ finite dimensional. For another proof, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336559/dixmiers-lemma-as-a-generalisation-of-schurs-first-lemma.